# Binding HTTP response to Select dropdown in reactive form

Tags: angular, typescript

I am really struggling to bind the HTTP response from a 3rd party API to a Select drop down in my Angular Reactive Form.

I know how to populate the Select if I hard code it like:

```
    merchants = [
       new MerchantOptions('1', 'Fake Test' ),
    ];
```

but I am clueless as to how to populate the Select from an HTTP response?

I can't seem to bind the response to the form control?

Please can you kindly advise?

```
export class myComponent implements OnInit {
myForm: FormGroup; 
    stores = this.apiService.getStores()
                    .subscribe(
                        (response) => { 
                          console.log(response),
                          this.myForm.setValue(response)
                        },
                        (error) => console.log(error)
                    );  
constructor(private apiService: ApiService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
     this. myForm = new FormGroup({
    'merchants': new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
  });    
  }
```

My data model:

```
export class MerchantOptions {
  constructor(public id: string, public name: string) { }
}
```

This is what my form looks like:

```
                  <form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onPost()">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="merchants">Stores</label>
                    <select id="merchants"
                      formControlName="merchants"
                      class="form-control">
                      <option *ngFor="let merchant of merchants" value="{{ merchant.id }}">
                        {{ merchant.name }}
                      </option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
              </form>
```

API response Output in my chrome consol:

[image: Chrome Consol API response Output]

Please excuse any naming or typos above, I typed the above code snippets just to give you an idea not copy paste from actual project.

Answer (score 1):

```
export class myComponent implements OnInit {
myForm: FormGroup; 
 merchant: MerchantOptions[];
    stores = this.apiService.getStores()
                    .subscribe(
                        (response) => { 
                          this.merchant=response
                        },
                        (error) => console.log(error)
                    );  
constructor(private apiService: ApiService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
     this. myForm = new FormGroup({
    'merchants': new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
  });    
  }
```

use this `merchant` in your html as `merchant.id`, `merchant.name`

Comment: Thank you so much! 
Adding  merchant: MerchantOptions[];
Made all the difference.

Setting it to response did the trick!
this.merchant=response

You saved me from days of frustration.
Thanks again ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Try to declare the `marchants` property in `myComponent` and then populate it with data from your response. Something like:

```
export class myComponent implements OnInit {
    myForm: FormGroup; 
    merchants: any;
    stores = this.apiService.getStores()
                    .subscribe(
                        (response) => { 
                          this.merchants = response;
                        },
                        (error) => console.log(error)
                    );  
    constructor(private apiService: ApiService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this. myForm = new FormGroup({
          'merchants': new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
        });    
    }
}
```

Then in your template just use the `merchants` array like:

```
<option *ngFor="let merchant of merchants" value="{{ merchant.ID }}">
    {{ merchant.name }}
</option>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction and getting this post going your answer was invaluable!